# POST'ing multiple comments using file_put_contents

Tags: php, html, post

Ok, so here is my page (basic template recreated for practice):
http://puu.sh/fRn4b/6d83015087.png

Its all static, bar the form.

What I am attempting to do with said form is to get the contents entered to show up in the little gray box just below (it has overflow set so scroll would be enabled once full).

I started with this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br>
<textarea name="comment" id="comments" rows="10" required placeholder="Enter your thoughts"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
                $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
                $comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
                $fullcomment = "<h2>".$name."</h2><p>".$comment."</p>";
                echo $fullcomment;

            }
```

That worked, and with the css it looked quite nice. However it would only post one comment and that comment would be lost on reloading. I wanted it to stick. So then the next attempt was:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
                $file ="./index.php";
                $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
                $comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
                $fullcomment = "<h2>".$name."</h2><p>".$comment."</p>";
                file_put_contents($file, $fullcomment, FILE_APPEND);

            }
```

Now upon submitting the form, nothing would happen (including no errors). Is it not possible to use file_put_contents on the file said function(?) is in? Because I tried changing the $file to "./index.txt" and that worked, it created a new file and added the forms content within.

As you can probably tell I am extremely new to this. This is me learning. I pick up new things and I think of ways I could apply them, even if said ways are not the most efficient method.

Any help would be great thank-you!
It does work but it adds the content at the end of the document, not within the comment box. Must need to find a different method.

Edit 2: I suppose I could just take the contents from the index.txt troubleshoot and add it to the .php file, but that seems a bit roundabout.

Edit 3: That worked yuhp. Although now refreshing index.php results in repeating the last entered form content, which is rather annoying. Would the solution to that be resetting the variables after the code has run?

Comment: looks like you're on the right path. If you want your comments to 'stick', you should store them in a file. I would not actually modify the `index.php` file though... code modifying code hurts my head. Maybe store it in 'comments.txt' and read from that file.

Another common way to do this is to use a database (for example MySQL). There is a lot of stuff written about how to do this, a simple Google search should help you out there. If you continue to learn web development, you probably want to get into this database stuff at some point.

Comment: to respond to your question in Edit 3: no, that would not work. Basically, your PHP script has no way of telling whether the user just refreshed the page or that the user actually took the time to type out an exact duplicate of the previous comment. A way to go would be to compare the comment currently being posted to the previous one and discard it if they are identical (much to the dismay of the user that took the time to re-type the previous comment exactly... for whatever reason)

Comment: Yes, ended up just converting the index.txt test to comments.txt. Thought editing code within code might be a problem but it seemed more efficient, but anyhow.  On the issue of duplicate comments, perhaps then resetting the link somehow to revert the form to empty? Not necessary, I'm just trying to get the idea I had for this to be bug free, but it works as it is so I'm happy with that! Thank-you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to solve this problem, but if you are not familiar with it, you can try this out :

```
$file ="./comments.txt";
// When you the page is loaded, get the comments from 'comments.txt'
$fullcomment = file_get_contents($file);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) {
       $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
       $comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
       $fullcomment = "<h2>".$name."</h2><p>".$comment."</p>";
       file_put_contents($file, $fullcomment, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing. So thank-you!